# Unbind only one project in a vss-controlled solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

My team and I are working with a VisualStudio solution under the VSS source control. We have several projects under our one solution.

We are planning on moving to Git and we would like to have a migration phase where we would have X projets under VSS source control and Y projects under Git source control.

The main problem here is that when I try in Visual studio (2010 or 2012) to go to "File" => "Source control" => "Change source control", I can't unbind only one project, they are all selected and I can only unbind them all.

Is there a way to unbind one of the Visual Studio projects and keep the others bound to VSS ?

Thanks for your help.

Florian.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create two solution files for the projects using VSS and Git.

Try the steps like below:

1. Unbind the whole solution from VSS
2. Create a copy of the solution and you can copy the projects for Git from here.
3. Bind back the solution to VSS source control in Visual Studio
4. Remove the projects for Git from the VSS solution